# Matomo/Piwik: How to fetch data for a particular timeframe using the Reporting API?

Tags: matomo

How do I use **Live.getLastVisitsDetails** & **segment** to fetch data between a particular timeframe?
For example, fetch data between 2-4 pm on 8th October. It's not letting me put **serverTimestamp** in the segment parameters.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `period` parameter of the API?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to limit the time of the returned data. So the minimum is fetching the data for the whole day.

Comment: I did a workaround. Fetched all the visitorIds from Piwik's MySQL database for that time frame. Used `segment` to fetch data of those visitorIds.